# Explain the How the following output came for following code in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
 int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}, y[5]={5,4,3,2,1}, res[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
 int i=0,j=0;
 while(i++<5)
 {
   res[i] = x[i]-y[i]; 
 }
 clrscr();
 cout<<"Content\n";
 i=0;
 do
 {
  cout<<x[i]<<"\t"<<y[i]<<"\t"<<res[i]<<"\n";
  i++;
 }while(i<5);
 getch();
}
```

Output: 
  [Click & View the Ouput of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IplvH.jpg)

In the output in first line Why y[0] show -1 instead of 5?

Comment: Please copy and paste code as properly formatted *text* - images are not helpful or useful and can not be searched.

Comment: Use (a) a debugger (b) a real programming environment such as gcc or msvc (c) text instead of screenshots. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: explain why you post the question?

Comment: Stop your attempts to be "clever" and use `for` statements. Your problem will disappear.

Comment: .... while(i++<5)  has the range [1, 5]. Hence your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Mr.Marian Spanik thank you for replied, I dont want the alternate way, i need why the output came like this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all in this while loop:

```
while(i++<5)
 {
   res[i] = x[i]-y[i]; 
 }
```

`i` will start from 1, since the condition has a side-effect of post-increment. So you are never changing `res[0]` which is why you see a `0` when you print `res[0]`. And regarding the value of `y[0]`, the while loop will run till `i` is 5. So finally you have something like:

```
res[5] = x[5] - y[5];
```

Writing into `res[5]` is corrupting the location `y[0]`.